# Using GROUP-BY-HAVING on two joined tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to join two tables, and select columns from both based on where constraints as a well as a  group-by-having condition. I'm experiencing some issues and behavior that I do not understand. I'm using sybase. A simple example below

```
CREATE TABLE #test(
name varchar(4),
num  int,
cat  varchar(3)
)

CREATE TABLE #other(
name varchar(4),
label varchar(20)
)

Insert #test VALUES('a',2,'aa') 
Insert  #test VALUES  ('b',2,'aa') 
Insert  #test VALUES  ('c',3,'bb')
Insert  #test VALUES ( 'a',3,'aa')
Insert  #test VALUES ( 'd',4,'aa')

Insert #other VALUES('a','this label is a') 
Insert  #other VALUES  ('b','this label is b') 
Insert  #other VALUES  ('c','this label is c')
Insert  #other VALUES ( 'd','this label is d')


SELECT t.name,t.num,o.label  
FROM #other o inner JOIN #test t ON o.name=t.name 
WHERE t.name='a' 
GROUP BY t.name 
HAVING t.num=MAX(t.num)
```

I get non-sense when I have the `GROUP BY` (the label columns are clearly related to a different t.name). If I cut out the `GROUP BY` statement the query behaves as I would expect, but then I am forced to use this as a subquery and then apply

```
SELECT * FROM (subquery here) s GROUP BY s.name having s.num=MAX(s.num)
```

There has to be a better way of doing this. Any help and explanation for this behavior would be very appreciated.

**I should clarify. In my actual query I have something like 
    SELECT .... FROM (joined tables) WHERE name IN (long list of names), GROUP BY .....

Comment: Since `WHERE t.name='a'`, I don't understand the point of `GROUP BY t.name`. Please clarify it by displaying output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, if I understand your query well.

```
SELECT t.name,t.num,o.label  
FROM #other o inner JOIN #test t ON o.name=t.name 
WHERE t.name='a' AND t.num=MAX(t.num)
```

Comment: The issue is I want the max(t.num) for each t.name. I know that doesn't make much since here since I'm doing t.name='a', but in my actual query I have t.name in ('large list of letters')

Answer (score 0):

Your GROUP BY must include t.name, t.num and o.label.  If you do this

```
GROUP BY t.name, t.num, o.label
```

then the query executes without error.

However you're not computing any aggregate values in the group by.
What are you trying to do?

Comment: This was a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. In my actual query I'm trying to get the latest dated record (i.e. max t.num) for each t.name

Comment: @jpc: see John Dewey's answer, is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, running this...

```
SELECT t.name, num=MAX(t.num), o.label
FROM #other o
INNER JOIN #test t ON o.name=t.name
WHERE t.name='a'
GROUP BY t.name, o.label;
```

...gives me this result:

```
name num         label
---- ----------- --------------------
a    3           this label is a
```

Comment: I don't think I phrased my question correctly. I apologize. Basically, the reason I am using the GROUP BY name HAVING num=MAX(num) is not really because i want the actual MAX(num) but rather because the data associated with that specific record is what i want. My actual project involves time series data for various entities across various factors, so I want to retrieve the latest date  for each specific entity(in my simplified example, name is the entity and num the date). But i also want a where clause before and the select columns to reference columns from the 2 joined tables.